# Escolha do tipo de função no javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou iniciando em java script, porem, não conseguir entender a principal diferença entre o uso destas duas funções, sei que pode ser uma pergunta básica porem não estou compreendo, em qual cenário posso aplicar uma ou outra.

```
function modificarNome(){
}

  var modificraNome = function(){

}
```

Comment: com certeza desculpa..Porem queria uma resposta mais formal.

Comment: Não tem diferença entre as duas no funcionamento, porém o segundo modelo você pode usá-lo para inserir uma função dentro de um objeto, por exemplo `var objeto = { modificarNome: function(){...} }` para usar: `objeto.modificarNome()`. Pode ser em qualquer nível do objeto: `var objeto = { funcoes: { modificarNome: function(){...} } }` para usar: `objeto.funcoes.modificarNome()`.